# Why does the CMake Linux binary depend on libgtk3-noscd?

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries, gtk3

I'm using CMake 3.21.3 - from Kitware's [download page](https://cmake.org/download/) (binary distribution). I've noticed that:

```
$ ldd `which cmake`
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0ed12000)
    libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x00007fdc4a890000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fdc4a88a000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fdc4a87f000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fdc4a85d000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdc4a719000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdc4a554000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdc4a8d3000)
```

contains references to two unexpected libraries. One is librt, which is probably explained by its use within `cmlibuv` (which CMake in turn uses); but the other, which I can't explain, is libgtk3-nocsd. Why would the CMake binary (not `cmake-gui` mind you) use this library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not linked against `libgtk3-nocsd`. Something in your environment has set LD_PRELOAD to add `libgtk3-nocsd`. Try running `ldd` again with LD_PRELOAD unset.

```
$ curl -s -L -O https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.21.3/cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

$ shasum cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
5461d4f066a728445e0b6be0e4d250b828323908  cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

$ tar xf cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

$ cd cmake-3.21.3-linux-x86_64/bin

$ shasum cmake
9c0032147cde3739e121c092013d13eb21c3ce34  cmake

$ unset LD_PRELOAD

$ ldd cmake
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffe0191000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f65af676000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f65af66b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f65af649000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f65af505000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f65af340000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f65af684000)
```

Comment: You're right. How weird! Who could be adding this to LD_PRELOAD?